# how to make Cypress.$ get the lastest value of the selector in a while loop

Tags: javascript, promise, cypress

I am writing a test to retry every 20 seconds on finding a dynamic text element which changes from 'Before' to 'After' after 10 seconds.

But my test would not go into 'else' clause in my code even the text 'After' is shown. I assume it is Cypress.$ selector did not get the latest value in each looping.

My cypress code is below,

```
describe('Test change text', () => {
it('test case',()=> {
    cy.visit('./test.html');
    cy.contains('Click me').click();
    cy.wait(1000).then(()=>{
        let found = false;
        let count = 0;
        while (!found) {
            //I assume the Cypress.$ selector below is not set in each loop
            let $changetext = Cypress.$('#changetext');
            if ($changetext.text() !== 'After') {
                cy.wait(2000);
                count = count + 1;
                if (count === 10) {
                    found = true;
                    console.log('The text is still Before');
                }
            }
            else {
                found = true;
                cy.get('#changetext').invoke('text').should('eq','After');
            }
        }
    });
})
})
```

The sample html code is below. I put the file under project folder.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>my test</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="changetext">Before</p> 
<p>After 10 seconds the text above will change to After</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("changetext").innerHTML = "After";
    },10000);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I expected the code will go into else clause after 10 seconds but it did not.
How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: If `cy.wait()` is thenable (line 5), it seems reasonable that it should be then'd on all occasions (see line 12). We might also expect `cy.visit()` to be thenable.

Comment: You're mixing async code (`cy.wait`) with sync code (`while` loop). Calling `cy.wait()` doesn't pause execution, it just adds the wait command into cypress command queue, which delays execution of ensuing cypress commands.